# Secure active storage with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Using devise gem to authenticate all users of an application. 
I'm trying to implement Active Storage.

Let's say that all users must be authenticated as soon as they reach the app:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!

...
end
```

How to secure the Active Storage generated routes?

URL of an uploaded file can be accessed without having to authenticate first. The unauthenticated user can get the file url generated by Active Storage.

Comment: Great question, I didn't even think of that. There must be some way to put the ActiveStorage URLs under the devise_scope, is my thinking...

Comment: Did you manage to solve this problem?

Comment: Sadly no I stick to shrine for the moment. I think it’s not mature enough for all projects. But I bet that they will improve as in future releases.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is not a full answer but a starting point:

The gist: You would need to override the redirect controller.

The [docs for activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/blobs_controller.rb](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/BlobsController.html) say:

> If you need to enforce access protection beyond the
> security-through-obscurity factor of the signed blob references,
> you'll need to implement your own authenticated redirection
> controller.

Also if you plan to use previews the [docs for activestorage/app/models/active_storage/blob/representable.rb](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Blob/Representable.html#method-i-preview) say

> Active Storage provides one [controller action for previews], but you may want to create your own (for
> example, if you need authentication).

Also you might find some relevant information in [this rails github issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31419)

**Update:**
Here is a minimal example that "should" work for preventing unauthorised access  to the redirects when using the `devise` gem.

How the url, that the user will be redirected to if logged, is then secured is still another story I guess. By default they expire after 5 minutes but this could be set to a shorter period like 10 seconds (if you replace line 6 in example below with `expires_in 10.seconds`)

Create a file `app/controllers/active_storage/blobs_controller.rb` with the following code:

```
class ActiveStorage::BlobsController < ActiveStorage::BaseController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  include ActiveStorage::SetBlob

  def show
    expires_in ActiveStorage::Blob.service.url_expires_in
    redirect_to @blob.service_url(disposition: params[:disposition])
  end
end
```

Please note that the only thing that changed from the [original code](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/blobs/redirect_controller.rb) is that the second line is added

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

**Update 2:**

Here is a concern that you can include in `ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController` and `ActiveStorage::BlobsController` to enable `devise` authentication for `ActiveStorage`

See gist is at https://gist.github.com/dommmel/4e41b204b97238e9aaf35939ae8e1666 also included here:

```
# Rails controller concern to enable Devise authentication for ActiveStorage.
# Put it in +app/controllers/concerns/blob_authenticatable.rb+ and include it when overriding
# +ActiveStorage::BlobsController+ and +ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController+.
# 
# Optional configuration:
# 
# Set the model that includes devise's database_authenticatable.
# Defaults to Devise.default_scope which defaults to the first
# devise role declared in your routes (usually :user)
#
#   blob_authenticatable resource: :admin
#   
# To specify how to determine if the current_user is allowed to access the 
# blob, override the can_access_blob? method
#   
# Minimal example:
# 
#   class ActiveStorage::BlobsController < ActiveStorage::BaseController
#     include ActiveStorage::SetBlob
#     include AdminOrUserAuthenticatable
#     
#     def show
#       expires_in ActiveStorage::Blob.service.url_expires_in
#       redirect_to @blob.service_url(disposition: params[:disposition])
#     end
#   end
# 
# Complete example:
# 
#   class ActiveStorage::RepresentationsController < ActiveStorage::BaseController
#     include ActiveStorage::SetBlob
#     include AdminOrUserAuthenticatable
# 
#     blob_authenticatable resource: :admin
#
#     def show
#       expires_in ActiveStorage::Blob.service.url_expires_in
#       redirect_to @blob.representation(params[:variation_key]).processed.service_url(disposition: params[:disposition])
#     end
#     
#     private
#
#       def can_access_blob?(current_user)
#         @blob.attachments.map(&:record).all? { |record| record.user == current_user }
#       end
#   end

module BlobAuthenticatable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    around_action :wrap_in_authentication
  end
  
  module ClassMethods
    def auth_resource
      @auth_resource || Devise.default_scope
    end

    private

      def blob_authenticatable(resource:)
        @auth_resource = resource
      end
  end

  private

    def wrap_in_authentication
      is_signed_in_and_authorized = send("#{self.class.auth_resource}_signed_in?") \
        & can_access_blob?(send("current_#{self.class.auth_resource}"))

      if is_signed_in_and_authorized
        yield
      else
        head :unauthorized
      end
    end

    def can_access_blob?(_user)
      true
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to give this feedback. I vote up but it still doesn't explain how to secure AS.  the links you mentioned just said "you'll need to implement your own authenticated redirection controller" well that what I believe too but still we (as users) don't know the path to realize that ;) that's all the problem.

Comment: I updated the answer with a small code example. I might have to implement this in the future (that's how I arrived at the question in the first place) and if/when I do I'll make sure to come back here and share the full solution.

Comment: Thanks for your update! I understand that if we want to secure AS we need to override few pieces of it. I'll accept the answer for now and wait for future updates ;) I'll also test it later on an existing app to see how it behaves.

Comment: One thing we have to test is that the "unprotected" old routes/controller are not reachable anymore.

Comment: That should be fine since you are basically using the same controller as before but with an added before_action to ensure authentication. Three thing worth mentioning imho:

1) to secure file previews/variants in the same way you have to override `app/controllers/active_storage/representations_controller.rb` in the same way.

2) The example above does not care about checking if a user should be allowed to view a particular file.

3) The controller will still return public urls (albeit fast expiring ones). I don't think that this is a problem in most cases, just something to be aware of.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to implement authentication for all endpoints provided by active storage, you can override the `ActiveStorage::BaseController` based on the [original implementation](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/base_controller.rb):

```
# app/controllers/active_storage/base_controller.rb

# frozen_string_literal: true

# The base class for all Active Storage controllers.
class ActiveStorage::BaseController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  include ActiveStorage::SetCurrent

  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```

Comment: Thank you, works! I've just added `include Devise::Controllers::Helpers` before calling authentication.

Comment: Be sure that if you are overriding a built-in rails controller, you reference the file associated with your current rails version.  For example: if you are using rails `5.2.6` then you would want to override this version of the `ActiveStorage::BaseController` file: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.6/activestorage/app/controllers/active_storage/base_controller.rb

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't satisfied with the solutions posted here: Reimplementing all the controllers and routing, or overriding the `ActiveStorage::BaseController`.

Both seem likely to break when the original source code changes.

What I've done instead is to patch the authentication into the existing `ActiveStorage::BaseController`:

```rb
# config/initializers/active_storage.rb
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  ActiveStorage::BaseController.class_eval do
    before_action :authenticate_user!
  end
end
```

I haven't yet tested all of Active Storage's functionality so I can't guarantee that it will all work, but so far it's working as expected for me.