# How to prevent user from accessing other user's Active Storage files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-activestorage

In my Rails app, I would like to prevent a user from being able to access another user's Active Storage files.

I tried the solution shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49808950/secure-active-storage-with-devise), but if I include a link_to to a specific user's file, I'm still able to access that file as a different user. For example, if I include the following code, my Rails app allows me to download the file, even though it belongs to a different user. I would like it to redirect somewhere else instead of allowing me to download the file if it's not mine.

```
rails_blob_path(User.find(57).file, disposition: "attachment")
```

I read that Active Storage uses "security through obscurity." Does this mean that, as long as I don't include a direct reference to a specific user's file in my application like I've done above (i.e., a Rails blob path to another user's file), I can be confident that users cannot access each other's files? Or is there another way to prevent this?

Comment: Why not use `pundit` gem to handle authorizations? Other way, just add a condition in controller action to redirect_to some_path if the user accessing that information is not the owner, in essence: `redirect_to some_path unless @file.user == current_user`

Comment: @ARK I'm having trouble figuring out 1) which controller, 2) which action, and 3) how to specify the selected blob (because users can have more than one type of file)

Comment: no user can access routes other than you have defined so you need to handle this in controller actions corresponding to routes which let any user access the blobs. I think that is pretty simple. If still confused, share code of any of your controller actions that gets blobs for a user and I will answer with the possible code.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this to allow access only to the file owner and admin user, for example in the songs's controller

```
before_action :require_same_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def require_same_user
  if current_user != @song.user and !current_user.admin?
    redirect_to root_path, alert: "Access Denied!"
  end  
end
```

remove current_user.admin if you don't have an admin user